# How to delete a podcast from new ios6 Podcast app?

Tags: podcasts, ios, iphone

The new ios 6 has Podcasts broken out into their own application.

I've got a bunch of old podcasts there for some reason. I can figure out how to delete all the episodes, but I can't figure out how to delete the podcast itself from the app. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Podcasts view (left tab), press the Edit button at the top left (you may need to scroll up to see it). Each podcast will have an (x) button in its top left corner. Hit that button (it's small and can be tricky, but it works) to remove the podcast. Use the Done button at the top left when you're finished editing.

[image]

Comment: aha! Thanks! I didn't see the EDIT button because it was scrolled away.