# How to delete multiple podcast episodes from iOS 6 podcast app?

Tags: ios, podcasts.app

I know how to delete a podcast subscription form the iOS 6 podcast app ([How to delete a podcast from new iOS 6 Podcast app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65460/how-to-delete-a-podcast-from-new-ios6-podcast-app)) but I'm having trouble deleting multiple *episodes* within a subscription.

Even if I have it set to save only "unplayed" and I mark everything as played, I still see hundreds of episodes listed (but not downloaded).  I realize they're not taking up space, but I'd prefer the list to be clean and just show the most recent / unplayed episodes.

In iOS 6 in general, is there a way to do a multiple select before a "swipe to delete"?  Or is there any other way to delete multiple instances of something without having to do it one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

The Podcasts app was updated for iOS 7 on October 22. I don’t think that this was a feature of iOS 6’s Podcast app, but if you are able to update to the latest version, there is an Edit button that can delete/mark-as-read multiple episodes or multiple subscriptions. (Assuming you’re not running an older device that isn’t compatible).

There isn’t a way to so multiple selects before a swipe to delete, though most apps have an “Edit” button to select multiple items before hitting the Delete button (as seen in Mail). In third-party apps, the interface depends on what the designer/developer built.